# Orbeon 4.4 and Oracle

Tags: orbeon

I posted this http://discuss.orbeon.com/problem-with-connecting-using-oracle-db-td2282023.html . I would like to use orbeon but it seems that I can not get the Oracle working with Orbeon correctly. I have used 4 days and still no luck and orbeon wiki is not telling the hole story. I have modified the web.xml and orbeon resurce file. Should this 4.4 version work with oracle? I am using Apache Tomcat/7.0.34 . eXist-db is not the solution for production purposes and therefore I need Oracle as DB.

thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest you re-post the information rather than just linking to it.  Making that information easily available to the people who might help you here, makes it more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: BTW it seems that the [linked thread](http://discuss.orbeon.com/problem-with-connecting-using-oracle-db-td2282023.html) did eventually provide an answer.